# ASP.NET Vnext Tag Helpers for Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, tag-helpers

I may use `<a href='/Area/Controller/action'> </a>` 
in asp.net vnext but just want to know whether we can use tag helpers like 
`<a asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName" asp-area="AreaName">` to redirect to the specific file in the area.

Will any one guide me how to redirect to a file in area using tag helpers.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from the following link which works well.

`<a asp-route-area="AreaName" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName"> </a>`

[github link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/28ca45e0779960b877f890cbff36f267603174fd/test/WebSites/MvcTagHelpersWebSite/Views/Shared/Customer.cshtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ReSharper it's IntelliSense could also override the Tag Helpers.
I described my solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630217/909980) post.