# MVC 6 Tag Helpers Intellisense?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tag-helpers

Is there supposed to be Intellisense for the new `asp-` tag helpers in Razor/MVC 6? I was following along on one of Shawn Wildermuth's courses on Pluralsight and everything functions properly, but I thought I should be getting intellisense when I start typing `asp-` as an attribute on a tag.

If it should be there do you have any ideas on what might cause it to disappear?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community, and **RC1-Final** versions of the .Net dependencies for Kestrel, Mvc, and TagHelpers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final"` to your project.json dependencies.

You also need to add `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` to your _ViewImports.cshtml to make the tag helpers available in al your views.

You can get more information at [aspnet 5 documentation page](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/intro.html)

Comment: Was missing the first step. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a one colour for tag name, and attributes after using the taghelper ? Can I change it somehow ? Can I change it do differentiate them from each other ?

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was ReSharper, disabling I get Intellisense back

Comment: Thanks for this, it was driving me insane :)

Comment: It is "fixed" in ReSharper v2016.2. In VS go: ReSharper -> Options -> Products & Features. There you can uncheck ASP.NET Razor, restart VS and done!

Answer (score 3):

Another thing, ensure that @addTagHelper in _ViewImports.cshtml is unquoted, for example:
`@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"` ----not good

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` ---good

This fixed mine...

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/484

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my project did not use the project.json, I use Visual Studio 2017 with the csproj file.

I simply needed to install (Tools -> Extentions and Updates...) this tool for Visual Studio (Razor Language Services):

[image]

After I did that, I restarted Visual Studio, it installed the tool and then I got the intellisense working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also have

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
```

in your `project.json dependencies`, you can see all of the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147096/550975

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to deactivate the IntelliSense of ReSharper (9.2) which overrides the TagHelpers.

Steps in the Visual Studio 2015 Menu:

- Go to ReSharper -> Options... -> IntelliSense -> General
- Check "Custom IntelliSense"
- **Except HTML** I changed dropdown entries to "ReSharper"
- Restart Visual Studio

The cshtml Razor page TagHelpers are now no longer overridden by ReSharper IntelliSense.

Comment: in visual studio 2015 in normal option there no IntelliSense

Comment: I wrote that in my case "ReSharper" was the problem and the "IntelliSence"-Option can be found in the Resharper-Options.