# HTML Helpers intellisense not working dotnetcore RC2

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following a Pluralsight course at [location](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app), which was build seemingly when dotnetcore had not yet hit RC2, so the instructions are a little off for the new bits.

Basically my razor views are not successfully giving me intellisense for helpers, though the helpers themselves are working save `asp-validation-summary`.

From a prebuilt template, I can see that recognized helpers get their own color as so:

[image]

But on the project in which I'm starting from an empty project and working my way up, I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, I'm not getting the helpers recognized by the razor view, although the helpers are being consumed correctly as shown by:

```
<form>

    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a minimum length of 5 and a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <label for="Message">Message</label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="4" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Message must be a string with a minimum length of 5 and a maximum length of 1024." data-val-length-max="1024" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="The Message field is required." id="Message" name="Message">
</textarea>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Message" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The above does not include the line from my screenshot:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly"></div>
```

because as soon as I add that line, the page does not render at all.  I receive a 500 internal server error.

Here are the relevant bits that I would have though would get my intellisense working, mostly taken from [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/484#issuecomment-219807702)

Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                );
            });
        }
    }
```

Project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Note that I've already seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098543/mvc-6-tag-helpers-intellisense), but this is related to (seemingly) different namespaces and a different RC.  The question linked is dotnet, I'm using dotnetcore, and RC2.

Any ideas?  Basic summary of question:  No tag helpers intellisense, though helpers (for the most part) work, aside from asp-validation-summary (so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a case of the ol "have you tried turning it off and on again?" Once restarting Visual Studio my helpers started having the correct color highlighting and intellisense.

Additionally, due to now properly having the intellisense, I can see that the syntax for the `asp-validation-results` has changed slightly from an earlier version of core.

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly"></div>
```

Now needs to be:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by repeating the same instruction from the link below and then restarted visual studio.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/484#issuecomment-219807702