# No IntelliSense for TagHelpers in Asp.NET Core RC2

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I tried everything possible and I still can't get IntelliSense to work with Tag Helpers.

What I tried:

[MVC 6 Tag Helpers Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098543/mvc-6-tag-helpers-intellisense)

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/484

This is happening on 2 computers. One with Windows 7 and other with Windows 10, both having VS 2015 Community.

Does anyone know hoe to solve this? Also, where is the official website for Asp.Net Core where I post these kinds of bugs?

Note: I also don't have Resharper in Tools->Options.

Comment: First step would be, upgrade to the RTM and stop using the outdated RC2, then tell us if you installed the proper tools (Runtime, SDK, Visual Studio Tools) for .NET Core

Comment: Migrating to RTM and installing the latest [SDK](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues.md#missing-sdk) did the trick. Thank you. Post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

**You have to add the required dependency and tool to `project.json` and probably restart Visual Studio after doing it.**

Add the following lines to the `"dependencies"` section of `project.json`:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
}
```

Then add this line to the `"tools"` section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

Remember to change the version numbers accordingly, if needed.

If IntelliSense still isn't working, restart Visual Studio.

You should see in bold both the element name and tag helper attribute name of every element that uses a tag helper attribute.