# Asp.Net MVC Core 1.0 - anchor tag helper with an empty area

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have an area called Admin, in one of my pages in this area, I want to navigate to the views that are located outside of my area, in fact it isn't in any area, with HTML helpers I could pass empty for that like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ArticleTitle, "Details", new { id = item.ArticleId,title=item.ArticleTitle.Replace(' ', '-'), Area = "" })
```

But when using tag helper, passing empty doesn't work:

```
<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-area="" asp-route-id="@item.ArticleId" asp-route-title="@item.ArticleTitle.Replace(' ', '-')" class="btn btn-default">Detail</a>
```

Worth to note that I've already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625817/asp-net-vnext-tag-helpers-for-areas), but my question is specifically about specifying the area in a way that it navigates me to the root of the site, outside of current area, and I know I can use normal URL, but I was curious if it could be done with tag helpers.

Comment: Which controller has a Details action in your solution? Maybe you forgot to provide asp-controller attribute? In this situation link will be generated right only if your current controller has a Details action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.NET RC2 it should work to use `asp-area=""`. And I'm pretty sure that with RC1 I got back outside the area even without specifying the area.

See my post on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4319

**Edit**

From my GitHub post:

With RC1 the following link had been rendered as a link to the root, even within an area:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
```

With RC2 (I had nightly build 1.0.0-rc2-20270) such links where rendered relatively to the area. This worked for me:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-area="">Home</a>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11978291)

Comment: Sorry. I added relevant information from the linked content.